# what is the best way to width html button in materialize or bootstrap frameworks?

Tags: bootstrap-4, materialize

I'm sensitive to know the best way to width buttons in html?frameworks grid or css class?

```
<div class="row"> 
   <div class="col s6">
      <button class="col s12">My Button</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it only depends on habit if I personally prefer materialize.